# Always saves 999.999999 when trying to save decimal

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, google-maps, decimal

I want to save the latitude/longitude from an address in my mysql database. The part of getting the latitude/longitude works perfect. I make sure that the longitude and latitude are saved in two hidden fields of my form before I submit the form.

The hidden fields have the correct value like for example:

```
<input class="longitude" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Longitude must be a number." data-val-required="The Longitude field is required." id="Address_Longitude" name="Address.Longitude" type="hidden" value="3.433212400000002">
```

In my Create Action I receive the following latitude/longitude:

```
Latitude: 509071452M
Longitude: 3433212400000002M
```

Then I try to convert it to Decimal like this:

```
viewModel.Address.Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(viewModel.Address.Latitude);
```

But he always saves `999.999999` in the database.

In my mysql database I have 2 fields latitude/longitude that are both Decimal(9,6).

In my Address Modal:

```
public Decimal Latitude { get; set; }
public Decimal Longitude { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in my view was `3.433212400000002` what in my backed was interpreted as 'thousands' ..
I changed the `.` to a `,` and it was fixed!